# Zxing Barcode Scanner Php select back camera at mobile

Tags: php, mobile, camera, barcode, zxing

i want to do, when i use mobile phone to scan barcode always asking **"select camera (front or back)"**. How can i select automatic back camera..
I want to use always back camera on mobile.
(so sorry for my bad english)

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
              let selectedDeviceId;
              const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader()
              console.log('code reader initialized')
                codeReader.listVideoInputDevices()
                .then((videoInputDevices) => {
                  const sourceSelect = document.getElementById('sourceSelect')
                  selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
                    if (videoInputDevices.length >= 5) { // KAÇ KAMERA OLURSA SEÇİM ÇIKACAK...
                    videoInputDevices.forEach((element) => {
                      const sourceOption = document.createElement('option')
                      sourceOption.text = element.label
                      sourceOption.value = element.deviceId
                      sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption)
                    })
                      
                      sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
                      selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value;
                    };  
                    const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById('sourceSelectPanel')
                    sourceSelectPanel.style.display = 'block'
                  }
```

Comment: This issue doesn't actually involve PHP. PHP is a server side language while selecting camera (and the posted code) is all client side.

Comment: So ?.. can i select the defaul camera with no camera select screen on mobile?

Comment: _"So?"_ - Only add tags that are directly relevant to the issue at hand. It's quite important since people (like me) are subscribing to specific tags and it's very annoying to see a bunch of questions that aren't actually relevant. I can see that you've changed it now so I just wanted to answer your question "so?".